# Repeat task, random message Mirc Scipt

Tags: mirc

Currently it reads the `text.txt` at random and it displays on a channel

```
on *:TEXT:!command:#channel:{
  /msg $chan $read(text.txt)
```

I don't understand how to make it auto execute at x minute intervals, whitout using the `!command`

I've beginner at this, I want to make it like a `/timer` but can add read random lines from the text everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I last worked with mIRC, so I had to look up the documentation on `/timer`, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
on *:TEXT:!command:#channel:{
  /timer 0 60 /msg $chan $!read(<textfile>)
}
```

This will execute `/msg $chan $!read(<textfile>)` an infinite number of times at 60 second intervals once `!command` has been entered into a channel.

If you need to cancel the timer for some reason, you would need to name the timer, which can be done by appending a name to the command, such as `/timerMESSAGE` or `/timer1`, and then including a command to turn the timer off, such as:

```
on *:TEXT:!timeroff:#channel:{
  /timer<name> off
}
```

replacing `<name>` with the name of your timer.

EDIT: Thanks to [Patrickdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1398579/patrickdev) for pointing out the difference of `$!read()` versus `$read()` for timer commands.

Comment: I was somewere close to what you said, but I get this error  /msg: insufficient parameters (line 2, remote.ini)

Comment: seems like you need for someone else to execute the script, beside you to make it run

Comment: @Alex_TNT Yeah, mIRC doesn't capture your own input for scripts.  Is `$read()` your own function?

Comment: No it's not my own function. I've changed the path to my drive one `$read(D:\Program Files (x86)\mIRC\defaults\scripts\text.txt)` seems to work, but it's repeating the same line

Comment: @Alex_TNT Looking at the documentation of `$read`, it looks like you need to specify the `n` switch after the name of the file in order to get it to not try and read it as mIRC Scripting Language code, so your call should be `$read(D:\Program Files (x86)\mIRC\defaults\scripts\text.txt,n)`

Comment: Change `$read` to `$!read` to change when the `$read()` is evaluated. By adding the exclamation mark, it won't read the contents when !command is issued, but when the timer is run (every 60 seconds).

Comment: Additionally, if you don't want !command to be typed at all, you'll want to look into events like `on START`, which triggers once every time the client starts.

Comment: @Patrickdev I've edited my answer to include your comments on `$!read` (with proper crediting to you). Thanks for that, I didn't know about that functionality of mIRC.

Comment: @Patrickdev events on start may cause trouble on disconnecting from network if you dont use an on disconnect event

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use this
if you disconnect from a network for whatever reason

ping timeout,broken pipe,connection reseted by peer,netsplit
it wont stop

the most efficient way is
using an on join event

```
on me:*:join:#channel:{
.timerrepeat 0 60 msg $chan $read(text.txt)
}

on me:*:part:#channel:{
.timerrepeat off
}
on *:disconnect:{
.timerrepeat off
}
```

this script will only triggers when you join on #channel

replace #channel with channel you want